# how to find and replace outerHTML in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want find and replace outerHtml content.

there is a "NSE_View_Delete" class, i want to replace it with "NSE_View_Delete_only_for_demo"

How can i do..Please help..

here is my hiddenfield..

```
 @Html.Hidden("ViewGroupDetails", Url.Action("ViewGroupDetails", "NSEDownload", new { acid = InsiderTrading.Common.ConstEnum.UserActions.NSEDownload }), new { @class = "gridtypecontrol", ctrtype = "link", gridcolumntype = @ViewBag.GridType + "_usr_grd_11073", param = "{'id':'MyID','class':'NSE_View_Delete','text':'','href':'" + Url.Action("ViewGroupDetails", "NSEDownload", new { acid = InsiderTrading.Common.ConstEnum.UserActions.NSEDownload }) + "& GroupId=<GroupId>','text':'View/Delete'}" })
```

it's render in dom as outerHTML(in browser) as follow

```
<input class="gridtypecontrol" ctrtype="link" gridcolumntype="508005_usr_grd_11073" id="ViewGroupDetails" name="ViewGroupDetails" param="{'id':'MyID','class':'NSE_View_Delete','text':'','href':'/NSEDownload/ViewGroupDetails?acid=223&amp; GroupId=<GroupId>','text':'View/Delete'}" type="hidden" value="/NSEDownload/ViewGroupDetails?acid=223">
```

js code as bellow

```
 if (obj.aData['nse_grd_50431'] != null) {
                debugger;
                var abc = obj.aData['nse_grd_50431'];

                if(abc==0)
                {

                    debugger;

                    var dom_value = $("#ViewGroupDetails").get(0);

                    var abc= dom_value.outerHTML.replace('param="class: NSE_View_Delete_only_for_demo;"')

                    alert(abc);
                }
            }
```

Please Help..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to replace an attribute of a HTML element and if that is the case you can use *attr()* method like below

```
$("#ViewGroupDetails").attr("param").replace("NSE_View_Delete", "NSE_View_Delete_only_for_demo")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not outerHTML this is attribute, so you should replace it.
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp

Comment: While this link may answer the question, always try to provide the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. This is not a good practice since if the link breaks in time this answer will not longer be useful.